# jQuery data select from multiple names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set-up like this, where I need to get one of the `data-target`s:

```
<div data-target="one">One</div>
<div data-target="two">Two</div>
<div data-target="three">Three</div>
```

How do I go about writing a selector that would allow me to target the `data-target="one"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the basic [**Attribute Selector**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) for this. So, you can target it this way:

```
$('[data-target="one"]');
```

And getting the data element can be done using:

```
$('[data-target="one"]').data("target");
```

Make sure you use the latest version of jQuery. If not, you can also use **pure JavaScript** this way:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-target="one"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual [***CSS* selector**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) for a specific attribute works for data attributes too, `div[data-target="one"]`

```
function jChoice(val) {
    return $('[data-target="' + val + '"]');
}
```